# regex: how to combine two exact match into one using re.sub() in python?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I would like to combine two lines of code into one.

The first one is to remove all string.punctuations. The code I used is below:

```
df[col].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[!\"#$%&\'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~]+', '', x))
```

The second one is to remove some special characters (I don't know how to express this kind of double quotes like `“’‘”`; these are different from normal `'""'` quotes):

```
df[col].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[“’‘”]', '', x))
```

I want to remove them all in one-line code. I tried to simply add second exact match to the first one, but it turns out the second match is not removed in the text. I wonder why and how to efficiently remove those `punctuations`.

The sample text needed to be cleaned could be:

```
text = '“Client” refers to Client or “”any User uploads or otherwise supplies to, or stores in, the Services under Client’s account.'
```

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: try this, ```df.col.str.replace(r"[^\w+|\d+]", "")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your responses, I believe this is the answer you're looking for:

```py
import re
text = '“Client” refers to Client or “”any User uploads or otherwise supplies to, or stores in, the Services under Client’s account.'
re.sub(r'[^\w|^\d|^\s]+', '', text)
```

**Output:**

```
'Client refers to Client or any User uploads or otherwise supplies to or stores in the Services under Clients account'
```

Replace all characters except:

- `^\w` word characters, like A-Z and a-z
- `^\d` digits
- `^\s` whitespace

This exclusive filtering is more effective than inclusive considering the breadth of your special characters list.

Comment: Thanks but I tried it and it doesn't work for the sample text. The second match cannot be removed @rgk

Comment: In that case, I think Sushanth's comment on your question is closer to your solution - removes all non-word and non-digit characters, but you'll also need to add `^\s` for whitespace. See my updated answer